# Inherit button function from one model into another - Odoo v9 community

Tags: python, odoo, qweb

I'm trying to use the functions/buttons from `stock.picking` model into `fleet.vehicle.log.services` one.

So far on my view:

```
        <record model='ir.ui.view' id='fleet_vehicle_log_services_form_inherit_1'>
        <field name='name'>fleet.vehicle.log.services.form0</field>
        <field name='model'>fleet.vehicle.log.services</field>
        <field name='inherit_id' ref='fleet.fleet_vehicle_log_services_form'/>
        <field name="priority">89</field>
        <field name='arch' type='xml'>
            <xpath expr="//form//sheet//group[1]" position="before">
            <header>
                <button name="action_confirm" states="draft" string="Mark as Todo" type="object" class="oe_highlight" groups="base.group_user"/>
                <button name="action_assign" states="confirmed,waiting" string="Reserve" type="object" class="oe_highlight" groups="base.group_user"/>
                <button name="force_assign" states="confirmed,waiting,partially_available" string="Force Availability" type="object" groups="base.group_user"/>
                <button name="do_new_transfer" states="draft,partially_available,assigned" string="Validate" groups="stock.group_stock_user" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
                <button name="do_print_picking" string="Print" groups="stock.group_stock_user" type="object" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', 'not in', ('assigned', 'partially_available'))]}"/>
                <button name="%(stock.act_stock_return_picking)d" string="Reverse" states="done" type="action" groups="base.group_user"/>
                <button name="action_cancel" states="assigned,confirmed,partially_available,draft,waiting" string="Cancel" groups="base.group_user" type="object"/>
                <field name="state" widget="statusbar" statusbar_visible="draft,confirmed,partially_available,assigned,done" statusbar_colors='{"shipping_except":"red","invoice_except":"red","waiting_date":"blue"}'/>                
            </header>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```

On the model:

```
    _inherit = "fleet.vehicle.log.services"
    stock_picking = fields.Many2one("stock.picking", "Picking")
    state = fields.Selection(string="Estados", store=True, readonly=True, related="stock_picking.state")
```

So far, `state` field shows fine, no problem with that, but I can't seem to make the buttons work, they just doesn't appear on the view.

I guess I need to relate these functions to `stock_picking` as I did with `state`, but these are function fields...

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it. The header tag must be a direct child of the form tag. So changing that line `<xpath expr="//form//sheet//group[1]" position="before">` to `<xpath expr="//form/sheet" position="before">` should help.

As to calling those functions, I'd try with :

```
from openerp import models, api

class FleetVehicleLogServices(models.Model):
    _inherit = "fleet.vehicle.log.services"

    stock_picking = fields.Many2one("stock.picking", "Picking")
    state = fields.Selection(string="Estados", store=True, readonly=True, related="stock_picking.state")

    @api.multi
    def action_confirm(self):
        for record in self:
            record.stock_picking.action_confirm()
        return True
```

And you can continue this way with the other methods.

Comment: Hi, awesome! Thank You very much, but ehre is something weird, I mean, now the buttons show, but when I save the record, they disappear, and the states just show up, but no change in colors or anything, this partly solves it, but, do You have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: Could it be permission related?

Comment: Or maybe it is because I'm not calling the other methods... I'm going to try and write You back

Comment: Hi, sorry, tried all possibilities, yes, the buttons don't show after I save the document, I can click on them, they seem to work, but they disappear soon after, and the states don't change color, do you think is because of something not that complicated? Maybe permissions?

Comment: Or maybe some other stock.picking fields I should call from this method?

Comment: When you create your record, do you provide a stock picking ? You should mark that field as required `stock_picking = fields.Many2one("stock.picking", "Picking", required=True)` because if it does not exist, nor would the state field (it would exist but it won't have a value, it will default to False). And calling those methods won't work either because in `record.stock_picking.action_confirm()` the stock_picking does not exist.

Comment: And if the state always default to False, these buttons will never appear because some appear only when the state is 'draft' or when the state is 'assigned'. None will appear if state is False.

Comment: Hi, no, the stock.picking should be created from this record :(, it's not like I'm selecting it, it doesn't exist, let me see

Comment: Yeah, you're totally right, now it works, but I should create it from this record, nevermind, gonna open a new question for that :), thank you